# Finite Summation of Fractional Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a finite summation series of identical fractions e.g $ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{3}$. Now lets say I add one to the denominator for the first two values of the series. I now have $ \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3}{2}$. Now I do it again but this time to the first three values of the series.
$ \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{79}{60}$. To complicate things again I add one to the denominator of the *last* three values of the series too. $ \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{11}{10}$

Is there an easy direct method to figure out the final answer $\frac{11}{10}$ given that we know that we did $[2,3]$ additions to the left of the series, and $[3]$ additions to the right of the series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, lets say we are summing $n$ fractions $\frac{p}{q}$ and add $x$ to the denominators of $m$ terms.

The sum of the original series is $s = \frac{np}{q}$.

The sum of the new series is $s' = \frac{np}{q} - \frac{mp}{q} + \frac{mp}{q + x} = (m - n)\frac{p}{q} + \frac{mp}{q + x} = \frac{m - n}{n}s + \frac{mp}{q + x}$.

Repeating in this manner will allow you to generalize this to raising the denominator of some number of terms arbitrarily many times.

Comment: Of course I am making the assumption $m \leq n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think it quite answers the question. I'm adding one to the denominators of the series for m terms, multiple times but to the same original series, not the new one. Also, I need to take into account whether the m terms are raised from the left or the right of the series.

Comment: Adding multiple times to the original series is the same as adding to the original series then the new series then the new new series etc. Although I do agree a problem occurs when you add to denominators which are different, but you can break the series up to avoid this problem.